# Dependence of Heat Capacity on Temperature

Tags: thermodynamics

I was studying about the graph of dependence of heat capacity on temperature.

[image]

As you can see in this picture, heat capacity with constant volume increases near 0K.
As the temperature keeps rising, it converges to 3R.

I was finding out why these changes happen. In the textbook, the author explained like this.

For the increasing part,

> This corresponds to an increased ability of the lattice waves to enhance their average energy with increasing temperature.

And, for the converging part,

> The quantity of energy required to produce a 1-degree temperature change is constant.

However, I could not understand about the reason of converging part.

I think the energy required to produce a 1-degree temperature change can be constant, but how this can be only applied only for converging part?

Comment: That's the definition of converging: it approaches and then reaches (matches) a determined value. To understand this you need to study statistical mechanics, which provides theories that explain the changes in $C_V$ with temperature.

Comment: The heat capacity is the slope of internal energy with temperature ($C_V=\partial U/\partial T|_V$ ) so as more energy is added by increasing temperature the rate at which this increases eventually becomes constant  (as energy levels now v numerous) and hence the $C_V$ is constant. Similarly at v low $T$ v few energy levels can be populated and $U$ is almost constant, as they become populated $U$ increases and so does $C_V$.